# How to get data from parent and child table on the basis of status where foreign key have different status for every row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables with foreign key relationship. Situation is I have a `case` and a `case` have many `revision`s and every `revision` have its own `status`. I want to get parent table data and child data if only specific row of foreign key table status is changed

Table `Case`

```
id      case_no    patient_name  age
1       12564        abc         78
2       1256         lkj         63
3       125          bdhf        23
```

Table `Case_Revisons`

```
    id      case_id    revison         status
    1         1           0           assesemnt
    2         1           1           assesment
    3         1           2           treatment
    4         2           2           assesment
    5         3           1           assesment
```

What I want is all data all data from `Case` and `Case Revisions` table where status is `treatment`

What I tried:

```
$data['treatment_setup_cases'] = MedicalPrimaryCases::with('primaryCaseNo')
            ->where('impression_type', 1)
            ->where('status', 'treatment-setup')
            ->get();


 public function primaryCaseNo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PrimaryCaseNo::class, 'primary_medical_case_id');
    }
```

Comment: Please show relations between `Case` and `Revision`. What are these `MedicalPrimaryCases` and `PrimaryCaseNo` models? What tables are they stored in? It sounds like you have made some complications here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join here:

```
$the_data_you_want = Case::join('case_revisions', 'case.id', '=', 'case_revisions.case_id')
    ->where('status', 'treatment')
    ->get();
```

`PrimaryCaseNo` and `impression_type` were not mentioned in the explanation of the question so I ignored them, you can change this if necessary.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The idea of Eloquent is *not* to have to deal with joins and other SQL syntax.

Comment: Joins are part of Eloquent, actually, there's a subsection in Eloquent documentation just for them: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: this is getting all the result but what i want is different like see case_id 1 have three records with different status now i need if single status of child table against case_id 1 is different i dont want that parent and child except i need all the the data.